# STM32 LCD-TFT flickering

Tags: c

I'm trying to readout my SHT31 sensor which I wrote my "own" driver for. I´m using the STM32F429-Discovery.

To connect and receive data from the SHT31 I configured I2C and using in addition my PA0-Pin(Button).

I used Hterm to get my prints from my com Port.

Now I want to use my com Port only in case of I need to debug, but if I´m not debugging I want to see my results on the onboard LCD-TFT (ili9341).

Therefore I copy and pasted the BSP folder(STM32F429I-Discovery) of the CubeMX repository folder and the whole components folder and included my ili9341.h and stm32f429i_discovery_lcd.h and configured via CubeMX the DMA2D,LTDC,FMC(for SDRAM) and just activated my RCC Crystal/Ceramic resonater.

I could successfully use the LTDC in combination with my ili9341 driver to display different stuff on the LCD.

After I built a new empty project with a configured I2C,GPIO,DMA2D,LTDC,FMC and (only activatet) RCC.

(And any SPI because of the LTDC or ili9341 is referring to it)

There I put my SHT31 folder in and correctly included it.

Now if I want to display my received values or even try to display a string @ line (..) my display is only flickering as the picture shows below.

Can someone maybe help me out?

[image: Picture of my LCD result]

[image: Picture of my Clock settings in CubeMX]

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "dma2d.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "ltdc.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "fmc.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "SHT31.h"
#include "debug.h"
#include "../Drivers\BSP\STM32F429I-Discovery\stm32f429i_discovery_lcd.h"
```

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA2D_Init();
  MX_FMC_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  MX_LTDC_Init();
  MX_SPI5_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();


  BSP_LCD_Init();
  BSP_LCD_DisplayOn();
  BSP_LCD_Clear(LCD_COLOR_RED);
  BSP_LCD_LayerDefaultInit(LCD_BACKGROUND_LAYER, LCD_FRAME_BUFFER);
  BSP_LCD_SelectLayer(LCD_BACKGROUND_LAYER);
  BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAtLine(3, (uint8_t*)"Hallo");

  while (1)
  {

  }

}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 80;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_LTDC;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLLSAI.PLLSAIN = 50;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLLSAI.PLLSAIR = 2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLLSAIDivR = RCC_PLLSAIDIVR_2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

If you guys need to see more let me know.

Thanks for solutions.

Comment: Have you tried building a project that *only* displays text to the display (without any other peripherals, I/O, sensors, etc)? Start with that, and gradually build it up.

Comment: From a web search, I found: https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAtLine/cpp-bsp_lcd_displaystringatline-function-examples.html It uses (e.g.): `BSP_LCD_SetTextColor(LCD_COLOR_YELLOW);` But, more importantly, from: https://documentation.help/STM32746G/stm32746g__discovery__lcd_8c_source.html there's more setup to do. What sets width/height/pixelformat, etc [as in `BSP_LCD_LayerDefaultInit`]?

Comment: You have both C and C++ language tags.  Are you mixing the languages?  For embedded systems, I recommend either C or C++ and assembly.  Don't mix the languages unless you need to.  BTW, C and C++ are different languages.  C++ has inheritance, function overloading and references. The C language doesn't.

Comment: So yes I already could build a project that can display some strings, after I tried to implement my own picture all successfully. The setup behind(width, height, hbp, fbp, etc.) comes from my ili9341.h what I can also post. And I'm new in this forum I mixed the Tags by mistake sorry.